# Restore jobs from backup from other jenkins instance

Tags: cloudbees

I have installed the free enterprise plugins, and performed a backup to cloudbees.

My problem is that I can not find a way to load this backed up configuration of my jobs from my old instance into my cloudbees jenkins instance...
Is it at all possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible automatically yet, but we can do this manually for you, depending on subscription level. Please open a ticket and we can discuss.